# R variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, rcharts

I am displaying a map via `Leaflet` with `R` using the package `rCharts`:
I added some polygons to the map and I want to get some information by clicking on them. So far I managed to get a Popup window to display the features name. I would also like to display some values from R variables, but I dont really know how to pass them over/include them to the JavaScript statement (See code.)

```
map <- Leaflet$new()
      map$geoJson((polygons),
    onEachFeature = "#! function(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup('<b>Name:</b>' + feature.properties.NAME + '<br> <b>Precipitation:</b> INSERT R VARIABLE HERE')
    } !#")
      map
```

Comment: `var R = map` <- Is this code you look for today ??'

Comment: instead of "INSERT R VARIABLE HERE" i would like to insert a r variable. 

I.e.
`x <- 123

onEachFeature = "#! function(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup('<b>Name:</b>' + feature.properties.NAME + '<br> <b>Precipitation:</b> "x"')
    } !#")`

but that does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you can't just paste in the value to that character string. For example

```
map <- Leaflet$new()
map$geoJson((polygons),
onEachFeature = paste("#! function(feature, layer){",
    "layer.bindPopup('<b>Name:</b>' + feature.properties.NAME + '<br> ",
    "<b>Precipitation:</b>", varibaleName, "')} !#", sep="")
)
map
```

Comment: This is, of course, a workable solution. But I would sure like to know if its possible to pass values into the JavaScript.

Comment: @robin.datadrivers The only way you can talk to the javascript engine is via strings that you parse. You can't pass a variable "directly" from R to JS because they are running in completely different contexts (one on the server, one on the client -- no shared memory)